# How to switch user with pre-configured credentials in SSH Terminal after logging in as standard user

Tags: ssh, login, command, su, putty

I was wondering how to execute a command file where: After logging in as a standard user, I want to switch user to "username" with password being "password", I can successfully execute the command.txt using a batch file by testing echo.

However, I have no clue how to include the password in the command file which is executed by a batch file when trying to switch user.

P.S This is when I am already inside the SSH session as a standard user.

Comment: Do you have administrative access to the server?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `su` command followed by the username

Comment: you will be asked to enter the password of the user you input and then you will serve active as that user

Comment: I am talking about authentication without needing user intervention like specifying password and username in the command file so that user don't need to input anything to switch user. For example: Logging into an SSH session can be something like: putty.exe "IP_ADDRESS" -l User_name -pw Password. Because my server requires me to log into a standard user first before switching user to the root user, I want to automate this process. I have done the automating of logging into the session but I don't know how to do the same when switching user in the session.